# Different syntax for nodes with pos=x on a path with (A) -- (B) and (A) to (B)

Tags: tikz-pgf, syntax

I wonder why we need a different syntax for specifying `nodes` (and `coordinates`) on a path when using the simple `--` and the `.. controls …` system or the `to` operation.

Here’s an example to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw [thick] (0,0) -- (5,2)
        node [pos=0.2] {A}
        node [midway] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw [thick] (0,0) .. controls +(1,2) and +(-2,-1) .. (5,2)
        node [pos=0.2] {A}
        node [midway] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}% with wrong result
    \draw[line width=1pt](0,0) to[out=40, in=160] (5,2)
        node [pos=0.2] {A}
        node [midway] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[line width=1pt](0,0) to[out=40, in=160] 
        node [pos=0.2] {A}
        node [midway] {B} (5,2); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

When using `--` or `controls` it is possible to position the node *after* the second coordinate.

[image: simple --] [image: controls operation]

But with `to[in=x, out=y]` this won’t work

[image: to problem]

all nodes go to `(0,0)` (not the first coordinate it’s always `(0,0)`) an we must gove the nodes before the second coordinate right after the `to` operation

[image: right to result]

I guess this has to do with the way `to` works but I wonder why …?

Comment: I think this is explained in page 149 of the manual and that should be something to do with `\pgfpointcurveattime` command population. Also as a sidenote, it is now possible to put a node in the middle of an arc with the cvs version of pgf-tikz implemented in March.

Comment: "With great power comes great responsibility".  The `to` syntax is incredibly powerful and flexible, but as part of that it needs more precise input.  Relevant to this question, the `to` path is meant to figure out where the nodes go, and this can be done in any way desired (including ignoring the `pos` keys).  But to do this, the `to` path constructor needs to know the nodes on its path at construction time, which (as TikZ works as a parser) is when the target coordinate is read.  Hence for the best results, nodes should be specified before the target coordinate, not after.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: OK, I see … if you make this to an answer I’d accept it. Is your “nodes should be specified before the target coordinate” meant only for `two` or in general including `--`, `|-` and `controls` etc.?

Comment: Converted, and hopefully addressed that last point.

Comment: See also: [PGF/TiKZ: When should I choose "--", "to" or "edge" to connect nodes? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646403/pgf-tikz-when-should-i-choose-to-or-edge-to-connect-nodes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `to path` mechanism is extremely powerful.  Essentially, using a `to path` one can put *anything* on the path at the current stage in its construction.  When constructing a path segment, the `to path` machine needs to know the starting coordinate, the target, and any nodes to be placed on the path.  The latter is because the `to path` should have complete control, including deciding how to interpret the various ways of positioning a node on a path segment.

TikZ's path constructor works like a parser.  So it eats the input line, spewing out PGF commands as it goes along.  A `to path` constructor is invoked when the target coordinate is reached (but before it is processed).  Therefore any nodes that are to be involved in the `to path` construction have to be read before the target is specified.  It may be possible to specify nodes after the target, but whether or not this works will depend vastly on what the `to path` actually does.  In some simple cases, it simply inserts a more normal segment into the current path specification, in which case putting the nodes afterwards ought to work.  But if it does something more complicated then it will not.

With more simply path specifications, such as `--`, `-|`, or `.. controls ..`, then TikZ knows how the path will look so when handling nodes it can be a little more flexible as to when they are specified: there's no potential for surprises.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question. I guess I was confused because I thought that `--` is an abbreviation/synonym of `to[]` (without any options).

Comment: It is, but it's the other way around.  The default `to` action is to insert `-- node stuff (target coordinate)` into the path.

Comment: Ahh, then my intuition wasn’t so wrong :-)