# PGF/TiKZ: When should I choose "--", "to" or "edge" to connect nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a summary of the differences of "--", "to", and "edge" and what is the best current practice to choose one these path commands to connect nodes?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Let's look at this example.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,0.5);
    \draw (0,-1) to ++(2,0) -- ++(0,0.5);
    \draw (0,-2) edge ++(2,0) -- ++(0,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image: three lines]

Without options, `to` is really the same as `--`. `edge` is different, though: the edge operation adds a new path *after completing the current one* (see from where the vertical "stem" starts?)

The difference is that with `to`, you can have options that change the path (like `in`, `out`, `bend ...`), etc. This happens also with `edge`, with the plus that, `edge` being *another path*, you can change things like color, dashed pattern, etc.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,0.5);
    \draw (0,-1) to[bend left] ++(2,0) -- ++(0,0.5);
    \draw (0,-2) edge[red, bend left] ++(2,0) -- ++(0,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: second example]

Notice that `\draw (0,-1) to[red, bend left] ++(2,0) -- ++(0,0.5);`  will *not* create a red line... because the color is a *global* property of a path.

Another important difference is that if the starting point is a node, the `edge` operation acts as if one were using the node name as the starting coordinate, so it uses border anchors:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw}]
    \draw (0,0) node{} to[bend left] ++(2,0);
    \node (A) at (0,-1) {};
    \draw (A) to[bend left] ++(2,0);
    \draw (0,-2)  node{} edge[red, bend left] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: starting from a node]

Comment: +1 This is a super helpful answer!

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks!

Comment: We can use `+` in stead `++` in `\draw (0,-2) edge[red, bend left] ++(2,0) -- ++(0,0.5);` , that is, `\draw (0,-2) edge[red, bend left] +(2,0) -- +(0,0.5);`. In turn, it can be replaced by `\draw (0,-2) -- +(0,0.5);
\draw (0,-2) edge[red, bend left] +(2,0);` Evenmore, without using `edge`, we may code `\draw (0,-2) -- +(0,0.5);
\draw[red] (0,-2) to[bend left] +(2,0);
`

Comment: Yes, you can do with several paths all these things. The objective of my answer is to explain the differences, not advocating for `edge` or `to` ;-). I find using `edge` useful when you do not want to break the path, see for example https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#f0

Answer (score 5):

Here is my personal experience only. From [pgfmanual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), the keys `--`, `to`, and `edge` are used to **connect** 2 `node`s, or 2 `coordinate`s, or 1 `node` with 1 `coordinate`. Note that `coordinate` is a special (without content) `node`. I see that `edge` can be ignored. I never use `edge` when drawing with TikZ, and I feel absolutely comfortable and effective: the less keys I use, the simpler coding, the same output figure. In other words, I use plain TikZ.

> Only when `to` is used WITHOUT any other options, then it is abbreviated as `--`, meaning *straight connecting*. All other cases (`to` WITH some option like `in`, `out`, `bend left`, `controls`, `distance`, etc. see the list of options in *Section 74.3 Curves* in the pgfmanual), just use `to`.

For example,

- `\draw (A)--(B);` is the same as `\draw (A) to (B);`
- `\draw (A) to [bend left] (B);` works; meanwhile `\draw (A) -- [bend left] (B);` gives an error.

More examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) coordinate (A)    
(3,2) coordinate (B)
;

% "--" is "to" when it is used WITHOUT any other options
\draw (A) -- node [sloped,above,pos=.3,red] {x} (B);
\draw (A) to node [sloped,above,pos=.3,red] {x} (B);

% When "to" is used WITH some options, just "to"
\draw (A) to [out=90,in=180] node [sloped,above,pos=.7,blue] {x} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) node[draw] (A) {A}    
(3,2) node[draw,circle] (B) {B}
;
    
% "--" is "to" when it is used WITHOUT any other options
\draw (A) -- node [sloped,above,pos=.3,red] {x} (B);
\draw (A) to node [sloped,above,pos=.3,red] {x} (B);
    
% When "to" is used WITH some options, just "to"
\draw (A) to [out=90,in=180] node [sloped,above,pos=.7,blue] {x} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) node[draw] (A) {A}    
(3,2) coordinate (B)
;
    
% "--" is "to" when it is used WITHOUT any other options
\draw (A) -- node [sloped,above,pos=.3,red] {x} (B);
\draw (A) to node [sloped,above,pos=.3,red] {x} (B);
    
% When "to" is used WITH some options, just "to"
\draw (A) to [out=90,in=180] node [sloped,above,pos=.7,blue] {x} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```