# Draw path to relative position in one line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a 45 degree arrow pointing to a node like so

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (zero) at (0,0);
    \node[above right=of zero] (A) {};
    \draw[->] (A) to (zero);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but in *one line*. Is that possible?

I know I can use `\draw[<-] (0,0) -- ++(1em,1em);` but I would have to figure out how much `em` is equivalent to a `above right` and I want to use the positioning keys anyway (for example, to set a global distance). But that, I can't get to work because, for example, `\draw[<-] (0,0) to node[above right] {};` gives me an error.

Comment: with `\usetikzlibrary{calc} ` you could have this: `\draw [<-] (0,0) -- ($(0,0)+(1,1)$);`

Comment: It depends on your node distance (`1cm` by default) and if you use one value or two values there (`1cm and 1cm`). In the first case it's `++(45: 1cm)`, in the latter it's `++(1cm, 1cm)`. But you can always simply do `\node[above right=of {0,0}](A){} edge[->] (0,0);` and variation of that. You could also use a pin on the `zero` coordinate with the appropriate settings. The `ext.positioning-plus` library of my `tikz-ext` package allows access to the node distance via PGFMath functions if more manual control is needed.

Comment: `\node[above right=of {0,0}](A){} edge[->] (0,0);` is exactly what I was looking for. If you submit it as an answer I can accept it.

Also I would be curious why we have to use edge here and how it is different from the usage in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646406/289373) answer which I really don't understand.

Comment: `\draw[->] node … {} (A) -- (0,0);` or `\node … {} (A) -- (0,0) [draw, ->];` work, too. Edge has an implicit draw, is an extra path and remembers the node that was just placed.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

On `(0,0)` starts a 45º line with length `1cm`. On this point a node is placed (and optionaly `drawn`). By default the center of the node is placed on this point but `anchor=south west` changes it.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<-] (0,0)--++(45:1cm) node[anchor=south west, draw] (A) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]